# How do I change the opacity of a series in Highcharts?

Tags: hover, hide, opacity, highcharts, scatter

Okay, so I graphed a scatter plot in highcharts.  I want to make it so when I hover over a series, all of the other series dim.  I've tried changing the fillOpacity and the color properties of the markers and it doesn't seem to work.  This is what I currently have:

```
series:{ 
    events:{
    mouseOver: function(event){
    console.log("in");
    var series_to_keep = this;
    $.each(chart.series, function(seriesNo, serie){
        serie.hide();
    });
    this.show();
    this.select(true);
},
    mouseOut: function(event){
    console.log("out");
    console.log(this);
    $.each(chart.series, function(seriesNo, serie){
        if(!serie.visible){
            serie.show();
        }
    });
},}}
...
```

This currently hides the other series, but I don't want to HIDE them.  How do I just change the opacity of the markers of the other series on hover, then switch them back?  I can't find which properties need to be changed.  I've missed with so many and none seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [discussion](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7075&p=33437), you can use something like this to adjust the color dynamically:

```
serie.color = "#FF00FF";
serie.graph.attr({ 
    stroke: '#FF00FF'
});
$.each(serie.data, function(i, point) {
    point.graphic.attr({
        fill: '#FF00FF'
    });
});
serie.redraw();
```

Comment: Mark, that's awesome.  Thank you.  Where is the documentation for the point.graphic attribute?!

Comment: @user1126931, the "graphic" property returns the SVGElement doing the rendereing (in this case a SVGCircleElement since it is a "circle point").  The documentation for this element is not HighCharts specific:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/SVGCircleElement or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972065(v=vs.85).aspx